# Add multiple rows into a table based on a value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible using pure SQL to add multiple rows into a table based on a value in a given field?

I have table named products, for simplicity this is an example:

```
id, views
1, 4
```

For that row, I want to insert 4 rows into another table. How can I do this?

I've written a PHP script to do this but would prefer a SQL version but I have no idea how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need a way to generate values.  If you have just a handful, you can do this manually:

```
insert into table(id)
    select p.id, n.n as which
    from products p join
         (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
         ) n
         on p.views <= n.n;
```

If you have a table of numbers you can use that as well.